# Dynamical Font-size in TextArea - JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, font-size

I am currently trying to get into JavaFx and started writing a program similar to Microsoft Word or Pages on OS X. I had to realize that the TextArea is really limited when it comes to style, so I was wondering if there is a component that is editable (as in you can write on it) and is able to change font size/color dynamically (size and color are defined with a choicebox on the UI. 
I read a little but about binding style-types or setting css rules, but as far as I know there is no way to access Java components (choicebox) or even variables from the css style sheet, so it wouldn't be dynamical.

What I mean by dynamically change font size/color:

1. Type a character into the TextArea.
2. Double the font size.
3. Type another character, that now appears twice as big as the first one, that is still displayed in its original size.

I'm having a hard time explaining myself, if you have any questions, please ask and I'll try going into further detail. Thanks

EDIT: Something that might be important is the fact that I am using Scene builder to create my UI.

EDIT 2: Could I cheat my way around it using a Highlighter with the same color as my background?

Comment: There are no standard controls to do that in JavaFX; have a look at the third-party controls from [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX)

Comment: @James_D it seems so weird to me, that such basic functions aren't available. But RichTextFX looks perfect, I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: What about [HTMLEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html)?

Comment: as far as I understood the need, indeed the HTMLEditor seems to be exactly what @AaronPriesterroth is looking for ;o

Comment: How could I've possibly overlook that? This seems like the easiest solution, Thanks VGR and @Kwoinkwoin. Somebody create an answer already so I can give credit :P

Comment: I always forget about `HTMLEditor` as I find it so restrictive (no control over the actual controls that appear, e.g. suppose I want different font size options, the text content is not an observable property, etc), but yes, maybe that is the best option for what you are doing.

Comment: I have been looking into both for the last hour, and I have to admit I decided to go with the RichTextFX, for the exact reasons you just mentioned.